# Why is it not recommended to turn back immediately after praying in a temple?

Tags: belief, temple, gods, worship

I heard this long time back that one should not immediately turn back after praying, instead take at least 2 or 3 steps back and then turn around. The reason is one should not make their back face the deity immediately after praying. Is this true? If so why?

Comment: if you believe that God is only present in that deity idol then it maybe true, but if you sincerely love God and believe He is everywhere, there can be no such restriction. God is ever-present, ever-loving. Initially it is good to have fear of God and fear of punishment. But advanced devotees do not worship God out of fear of getting punished. They love Him sincerely and know that He is everywhere. All the best.

Comment: @Sai- There certain protocols that need to be followed in whatever field you are. The same applicable to spirituality also. Vedas itself say that Sun, moon and all other celestials do there work out of fear of Supreme. Agreed pure devotees worship the supreme out of sincere love, hence they will try there best not break the laws laid down by the Supreme# Thanks#

Comment: @Krishna you are absolutely right. I **did not** mean to say that the protocols laid out by ancestors are invalid and have no place. Therefore I apologize if I came across in that way. My intention was merely to point out that just as initially as children we obey our parents out of fear of getting punished, but later on we realize their love for us. Then we obey them out of love, rather than fear. Similarly the advanced devotees choose to follow all the rules, not out of fear of the punishment, but out of love and to set an example to others. Thanks

Comment: @Krishna as for the rule that one should not make the back face the deity immediately after praying, I think that it depends on one's view on the temple and on the God. So it is a subjective thing. In my opinion, God is equally present everywhere so there is no question of turning one's back on Him, but not everyone needs to subscribe to that belief. That does not mean that one can disrespect the deity in the Temple. It just means that one can live happily knowing that God is present in all. Therefore I said that. All the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

God is everywhere, but Tirthas, holy places of pilgrimage and temples have a greater manifestation of God then other places. It is because they have been made holy by innumerable visits of pilgrims and holy men and women. The places can sometimes vibrate with holiness. When standing before a human king, the custom has been in many countries to back away from the king so as not to show your backside to the king as it was considered an insult to show your backside instead of your face to the king.

So it is with a murthi in a temple. The murthi is the representation of God. It literally vibrates with God's presence. Why not give the same consideration to the King or Queen of the universe as you would to an earthly king?

Most people show humility before those then consider their superiors. The same courtesy should be shown to God. God will not hate us or get angry if we do not, the humility helps us to learn to love God.